# Как сделать swap в Web3.py от MATIC на USDC

Tags: python, blockchain, swap, web3.py

Как сделать swap обмен между MATIC на USDC через Metamask Router, uniswap или другое.
У меня есть код и он отправляет средства тестовые но в метамаске не приходит  обратно.
Где мне взять abi и адрес контракта от Metamask Router, uniswap или других?

Код взял из: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138155/interact-with-swap-function-for-sushiswap-contract

Вот мой код:

```
import time
from web3 import Web3

class swapExample():
    def __init__(self, wallet: str, private_key: str, web3RpcUrl: str, 
        buy_amount: int, from_token: str, to_token: str, rourter_adress: str, abi: str):
        
        #Setup Wallet Informations and RPC
        #Usually we place these info in separate .env or .py or .json file.
        self.wallet = Web3.to_checksum_address(wallet) #your wallet address
        self.pk = private_key #your wallet private key
        self.rpc = web3RpcUrl #your node or use public rpc
        self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc)) #connect to web3

        #Setup Swap Value / Gas limit / Gwei
        #Change these values if you want.
        self.buy_amount = buy_amount #Ether value to spend
        self.gas = 500000 #gas limit
        self.gwei = 200  #gwei

        #Setup WETH token address (to spend) and Token address (to buy)
        #In my case I'll use WBNB to buy Safemoon token (at BSC Testnet)
        self.WETH = self.web3.to_checksum_address(from_token)
        self.token_to_buy = self.web3.to_checksum_address(to_token)

        #Setup router address (Sushiswap Router Address)
        #In my case I'll use Pancakeswap Router (at BSC Testnet)
        self.router = self.web3.to_checksum_address(rourter_adress)

        #Setup SwapExactETHforTokens ABI
        #You can get this ABI directly from Verified Contract Source Code at Etherscan
        self.abi = abi

        #Creating instance.
        #We can call contract functions with this.
        self.router_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=self.router, abi=self.abi)

        # #Do swap.
        # self.swap()

    #From here we are going to create Swap function.
    def swap(self):
        #building transaction with swap parameters
        #you can edit this if you want
        swap_txn = self.router_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
            0, #amountOutMin(slippage)
            [self.WETH,self.token_to_buy], #path (WETH,TOKEN)
            self.wallet, #to (your wallet)
            (int(time.time()) + 10000) #Deadline
        ).build_transaction({
            'from': self.wallet,
            'value': self.web3.to_wei(self.buy_amount, unit='ether'),
            'gas': self.gas,
            'gasPrice': self.web3.to_wei(self.gwei,'gwei'),
            'nonce': self.web3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.wallet),
        })

        #Sign swap tx and send to blockchain
        sign_tx = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_txn, private_key=self.pk)
        buy_tx = self.web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)
        print("Txn sent, awaiting for response.")
    
        #Await for result
        tx_result = self.web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(buy_tx) 

        # Transaction status verification
        # If status == 1: Swap success.
        if tx_result['status'] == 1: 
            print("Success! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return True 
        else: 
            print("Error! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return False

init = swapExample(
    wallet='адрес кошелька',
    private_key='приватный ключ', 
    web3RpcUrl='https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/цифры',
    buy_amount=0.0001,
    from_token='0x7D1AfA7B718fb893dB30A3aBc0Cfc608AaCfeBB0',
    to_token='0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',
    rourter_adress='0x1a1ec25DC08e98e5E93F1104B5e5cdD298707d31',
    abi= '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]'
    )

init.swap()
```